# NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition

Tags: c++, macos, gcc

My system is macOS Big Sur and I have a compilation problem. This is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

class view {
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

class tui : view {
public:
    void draw();
};

void tui::draw() {
    struct winsize size;
    ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &size);

    printf("x = %hu, y = %hu\n", size.ws_row, size.ws_col);
}

int main() {
    tui a;
    a.draw();
}
```

This is the error when I try `gcc -Wall main.cpp -o my_program`:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for view in main-c2a1d3.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for tui in main-c2a1d3.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "___cxa_pure_virtual", referenced from:
      vtable for view in main-c2a1d3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Do you know anything about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compile C++ code with a C compiler. Just use:

```
g++ -Wall main.cpp -o my_program
```

Comment: Just one step forward: why does compiling C++ code with C compiler would result in this linker error but others? Even, why linker error? Why not compiling error?

Answer (score 0):

`__cxa_pure_virtual` is defined by [libc++](https://libcxxabi.llvm.org/spec.html), which is not linked by default when using `clang` (/`gcc`). This function is implicitly used by `virtual void draw() = 0;`, so it will fail to link.

Use `clang++` instead (`clang++ -Wall main.cpp -o my_program`), which will link the correct runtime.